# Using CameraX for change background in camera preview

Tags: android, replace, background, preview, android-camerax

We are trying to add the option for users in our app to be able to change the background in a live preview screen before capturing the selfie image/video.

Any suggestions to how to do this.

All users are using the Samsung Galaxy S8 tablet

Preview is from the FRONT camera

Thanks All

We have tried using mediapipe https://github.com/googlesamples/mediapipe/tree/main/examples/image_segmentation/android
for segmenting the objects first but this option we have when multiple persons in the preview then there are issues also the process seem to be slower than what we expected.

We would expect a smooth approx 3-5 seconds max loading also we would like to be able to choose background from local gallery

Answer (score 0):

I would give it a shot with ML Kit. Docs state that:

> API latency can vary from 25ms to 65ms depending on the input image size, as measured on a Pixel 4.

You should probably use: `STREAM_MODE` for the `Segmenter`.

```
val options =
    SelfieSegmenterOptions.Builder()
        .setDetectorMode(SelfieSegmenterOptions.STREAM_MODE)
        .enableRawSizeMask()
        .build()
val segmenter = Segmentation.getClient(options)
```

Keep in mind it is extremely critical to build this only once and not at every frame. Keep it outside of your `override fun analyze(imageProxy: ImageProxy)`.

I would establish the logic this way:

1. Acquire each frame in your `override fun analyze(imageProxy: ImageProxy)`
2. Convert image to ML Kit's input type: `val image = InputImage.fromMediaImage(mediaImage, imageProxy.imageInfo.rotationDegrees)`
3. Pass image to `ML Kit Vision API`
4. Get the segmentation graphic result.
5. Place a Graphic View Layer on top of your camera preview view.
6. Make sure Graphic View Layer draws your background choice
7. Remove the segmentation mask area from the Graphic View Layer

Many of the above can be figured out at:

https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/selfie-segmentation/android

and

https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/blob/master/android/vision-quickstart/app/src/main/java/com/google/mlkit/vision/demo/kotlin/segmenter/SegmentationGraphic.kt